# How to Handle 64-Bit Pointers with 32-Bit Lane Registers in SVE Gather-Load Intrinsics?

Tags: simd, arm64, intrinsics, sve

SVE offers various gather-load intrinsics. For instance, `svuint32_t m = svld1_gather_u32_offset_u32(svbool_t pg, const uint32_t *base, svuint32_t offsets)` loads `base[i]` into each lane `i` of `m`.

Alternatively, you can use `svuint32_t k = svld1_gather_u32base_u32(svbool_t pg, svuint32_t bases)` to load elements into `k`. Each lane of bases contains a 32 bit memory address as bases is of type `svuint32_t`. However, AArch64 (required for SVE) pointers are 64 bits. How can a 64 bit pointer fit into a 32 bit lane?

I assume the second variant can only be used when the pointers happen to fit into 32 bits. As this can't be guaranteed, how practical is the second approach?

I attempted to read the generated assembly code, but since it's not my strength, it didn't help me further.

Comment: Yes, if you have raw pointers but they fit in 32 bits each, the asm can use base=0 and the pointers as a vector of offsets, assuming there isn't a separate form of the instruction.  (Unscaled; otherwise use 34 bit pointers right-shifted by 2 with a scale-factor of 4, if they each point to aligned dwords.)  If you have arbitrary 64-bit pointers, you'll need to use them as 64-bit offsets, if SVE has an equivalent for x86's `vpgatherqd`.

Comment: How practical?   Allocate your data from within one big 4GiB arena (so you can use a fixed `base`), or use array indices.  Or use Linux `mmap(MAP_32BIT)` to allocate in the low 4GiB so pointers as 32-bit offsets from base=0 works.

Comment: ARM64 has an [ILP32 ABI](https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64ilp32Port) in which the entire program fits in 4GB and pointers are indeed 32 bits.  So this intrinsic could be used in that setting. I was going to guess the `u32base` form was just the special case where the base register was `xzr`, but it seems not.  It's actually a form of the instruction which takes a 5-bit immediate that's left-shifted 2 bits and added to each index, and this is the special case where that immediate is 0.

Comment: If you truly need 64-bit pointers then svld1_gather_u64base_u64, with a follow-on reduction.